# Power Query to search/download data using API/JSON

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to lookup information through a website API by an identifier known as an NPI.  For example, if a cell contains 1669578803, I am looking to get the corresponding information..

The API documentation info and documentation is here:

https://data.cms.gov/provider-characteristics/medicare-provider-supplier-enrollment/medicare-fee-for-service-public-provider-enrollment

Link "Accees API" has info.

The problem I am having is that when I goto "Data...From Web" and enter in the URL (https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/9138d25a-5d85-4a12-b3c9-070e544486db/data), it loads the first 1,000 rows
as Records and not sure how to query for the specific NPI that more than likely, will be past the first 1,000 rows (1.5 million rows total).

Any idea as to how to accomplish this?  Using Excel 365.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to use a filter on your query.

eg:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/9138d25a-5d85-4a12-b3c9-070e544486db/data?filter[NPI]=1669578803")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"NPI", "PECOS_ASCT_CNTL_ID", "ENRLMT_ID", "PROVIDER_TYPE_CD", "PROVIDER_TYPE_DESC", "STATE_CD", "FIRST_NAME", "MDL_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "ORG_NAME", "GNDR_SW"}, {"NPI", "PECOS_ASCT_CNTL_ID", "ENRLMT_ID", "PROVIDER_TYPE_CD", "PROVIDER_TYPE_DESC", "STATE_CD", "FIRST_NAME", "MDL_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "ORG_NAME", "GNDR_SW"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

**=>**
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I knew the filter criteria would be part of the URL, I just couldn't figure it out the exact syntax.  That worked..